# Best practice to use SASS and Symfony

Tags: css, sass, symfony, assetic

I integrated SASS css in my Symfony 3.1 project following the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/asset_management.html).

Now in my `baseLayout.html.twig` I have:

```
{% stylesheets filter="scssphp,cssrewrite" output="css/app.css"
    "assets/vendor/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss"
    "assets/css/_variables.scss"
    "assets/css/layout.scss"
    %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
{% endstylesheets %}
```

In `_variables.scss` I have:

```
// Colors
$grey-super-light: #fafafa;
```

so I would like to use the variable `$grey-super-light` in `layout.scss`

```
body {
  background-color: $grey-super-light;
}
```

but when I run php bin/console assetic:dump I get this error:

```
[Leafo\ScssPhp\Exception\CompilerException]
Undefined variable $blue-veruscript: line: 2
```

I know one solution would be to import `_variables.scss` directly in `layout.scss` but I would like to know if there is a way to use the assetic import to share variables (and also other SASS features) between different files.
In this way I avoid to end up with a lot of imports in my `layout.scss`, and I could also import full directories without listing file by file.

Any idea if this is possible?

Comment: While not actually depreciated, the assetic bundle is sort of frowned upon in S3.  Not even included by default anymore.  If you really want to follow a mythical best practice then stop using assetic and instead install a non-php sass processor.  Perhaps one driven by npm/gulp.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will try like you suggest.